# How can i save iMessage conversations on OSX?

Tags: macos, backup, imessage

Is there any way to store a iMessage conversation which i wrote on a Mac? I've found lot's of programs which allow to do this with conversations on an iPhone but not on a Mac.

I tried the approach with the ~/Library/Messages/Archive - but there ain't no Archive folder - just the chat.db and a folder called /Attachments.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but in OSX 10.10 it works!

For non-technical folks:

1. open terminal
2. type `cd  ~/Library/Messages/Archive`
3. type `open .`

this opens the Archive folder for you. You can then copy the content.